# GridView Paging Issue

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview, paging

I am using a gridview control and performing Paging and Sorting manually.
Here is the method of Paging:

```
protected void gdvMainList_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gdvMainList.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gdvMainList.DataSource = dtConsentReleaseList;
        gdvMainList.DataBind();
    }
```

I have a static datatable having a column Id:

```
dtConsentReleaseList.Columns.Add("Id");
            dtConsentReleaseList.Columns.Add("StartDate");
            dtConsentReleaseList.Columns.Add("EndDate");
            dtConsentReleaseList.Columns.Add("Contact");
```

I am assigning datakeynames "Id" in my GridView.
And I also have a print button in each row. When I click that button, this code gets executed:

```
else if (e.CommandName == "New")
        {                
            int selectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            int consentReleaseId = Convert.ToInt32(gdvMainList.DataKeys[selectedIndex].Value);
            string openReportScript = Utility.OpenReport(ResolveClientUrl("~/Reports/Consumer/ConsentReleaseReport.aspx?Id=" + consentReleaseId + "&ReportTitle=ConsentForRelease"));
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upConsentRelease, upConsentRelease.GetType(), "Pop up", openReportScript, true);
        }
```

but when I change the page and clicks print button, an exception occurs on this line :

```
int consentReleaseId = Convert.ToInt32(gdvMainList.DataKeys[selectedIndex].Value);
```

Exception is:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index
```

I guess I am doing something wrong in Paging method.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a value out of an array based on an arbitrary ID instead of the actual index. But you don't need to do that at all. You don't need to store your ID in the `DataKeys` and you don't need to access anything using the index of the item. Just pull your ID out from the `CommandArgument`.

```
<asp:ImageButton CommandName="New" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ID="ibtnPrint" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/print.png" />
```

And then in code-behind:

```
int consentReleaseId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
```

Comment: e.Item.ItemIndex is not there in my "e" because I am using this method: protected void gdvMainList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)

Comment: & it will not do anything I guess because my code is working perfect on the first page of grid. problem comes on the next page...

Comment: I've updated my answer. I was thinking of the `ItemDataBound` event.

Comment: sorry for late, but where to write this code: <asp:ButtonColumn CommandArgument="<%# Eval("Id") %>"/> I mean should I remove datakeynames ?

Comment: `DataKeyName` is not necessary in this case because you can set the `CommandArgument` property on the `Button` or `LinkButton` which causes the action in your ASPX or ASCX file.

Comment: Use some ingenuity, I don't have an ASP.NET project open right now. I'm just saying to add the `CommandArgument` property to whatever you are using to cause the post back (your "print" button). And set the value of that property to `<%# Eval("Id") %>`.

Comment: This is my code of button, I am using already command argument in it. Can I have two? <asp:ImageButton CommandName="New" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
                                            ID="ibtnPrint" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/Default/images/print.png" />

Comment: As I said before, a few times, you don't need the index. You just want the ID, right? So change your code to this: `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'` to store the ID instead of the index.

Comment: Thanks a lot Josh M.. It solved my problem.. You are 101% right! Thanks once again ... :-)

Comment: One correction I wanna make is: `int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);` does not work because `int.Parse()` always required a string therefore I used `Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)` .. Happy CoDinG !!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you bind the gridview in code-behind (possibly page_load event) and it doesn't hold the values on postback.

Also, try to pass the Id as CommandArgument. As far as I can tell, if you have access to Id of the selected record, you don't need grid's row index at all. (GridView passes row's index as CommandArgument by default)

Comment: Ultimate problem is I am not getting Id on next page of the grid. Any idea what happened on the next page?

Comment: and I am binding the grid in gdvMainList_PageIndexChanging method as well. Bt Id is not available

Comment: I guess that's the postback issue I mentioned. Once I implemented custom paging for gridview. But I ignored built in paging (And I'm almost confident that you'd end up with a solution like this.) I used a great custom control from http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/ASPNETPagerControl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Set the datakeyname right before you set the datasource and bind the gridview.

In addition,

```
string[] dk = new string[1] {"MyID"};
myGridView.DataKeyNames = dk;
myGridView.DataSource = ds;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: @asma - Sorry try `string[] dk = new string[1] { "MyID" };`

Comment: The problem is still the same. It is not getting datakeyname when I click print button.

Comment: @asma - you need to post more code, where else are you DataBinding() ? Its probably the way the asp.net page life cycle is handling all of this. RowCommand handler is run even before the page_load has been triggered. Ensure the grid view is bound already before you start paging through your dataset.  Also do you have viewstate enabled on the grid ?

Comment: I don't think your solution has anything to do with the problem @asma has described. You only need to set the `DataKeyNames` property once and you can rebind the `GridView` as much as you want.

Comment: @JonH: EnableViewState is not used in my grid

Comment: @asma why isnt it used?  Turn it on.